# Chip de autocomplete Mui cuando la propiedad Multiple es false

Tags: autocomplete, mui

en este [code sanbox: ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-frog-rkpch?file=/index.js) quiero utilizar el componente chip cuando la propiedad multiple es false en el autocomplete de mui, pero al seleccionar una opción también me carga el texto del valor seleccionado, como puedo hacer que cuando el usuario seleccione una opción solo se muestre el  en el textfield sin el texto del valor seleccionado?